# How to populate the next closest hour based on the current date in Salesforce apex

Tags: apex, event, calendar

How to populate the next closest hour based on the current date.The fields im using are of datetime datatype.

ex:If my current time is 8:15 am it should populate 9:00 am.

I tried using time class,datetime class ,math class to use round method.Please give me some suggestions.

Answer (score 1):

There's no method that will do this for you. I think you'll want logic something like this. One thing that's critical with DateTimes is to remember to always use either GMT methods or local time zone methods, but not to mix them - you'll get very strange results if you do.

```
public DateTime roundToNextHour(DateTime dt) {
    if (dt.minute() != 0) {
        return dt.addHours(1).addMinutes(-t.minute());
    }

    return dt;
}
```

The current time is 5:09 AM in Pacific time; if I do `roundToNextHour(DateTime.now()).format()`, I get

> 08:08:23:002 USER_DEBUG [11]|DEBUG|6/12/2019 6:00 AM

Likewise, provided with a time past 11 pm, I get wrapped around to the next day, as expected:

> 08:10:35:002 USER_DEBUG [11]|DEBUG|6/13/2019 12:00 AM

Comment: Thank you so much.